# between vs among

Tags: prepositions, between-among

> __ English, Hindi & French, I like English the most.

[OALD definition of between](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/between_1) doesn't list anything that would make me choose this word for this sentence.

[3rd point of among](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/among) lists that it's used when you are dividing or choosing something, and three or more people or things are involved.

So I guess we can use *among* in the above sentence. But I am not sure. I feel *between* suits better here. don't know why.

Comment: As [demonstrated at length in this answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/37637/2085), it is a myth and misunderstanding that *between* must be reserved for only two things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think *between* fits better. That's because here we are talking about three languages that represent themselves *individually and equally and NOT collectively.* Still, let native speakers put light on this topic.

> Between English, Hindi and French, I like English the most. (use 'and' over '&').

[This article](http://www.noslangues-ourlanguages.gc.ca/bien-well/fra-eng/grammaire-grammar/parmi-among-eng.html) will help you learn the finer nuance.

Comment: The excellent article you cite explains it with this bullet, I think: _Use_ between _before a series of singular nouns or pronouns_. The samples there seems to run parallel with the O.P.'s example sentence.

Comment: Another expression that would fit in the blank is "Out of": *Out of English, Hindi, and French, I like English the most.*